# BrowserModule has already been loaded

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7, lazy-loading

This is my code:

```js
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { LanguageTranslationModule } from './shared/modules/language-translation/language-translation.module'

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AuthGuard } from './shared';

    import { SidebarComponent } from './layout/components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './layout/components/header/header.component';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            LanguageTranslationModule,
            AppRoutingModule

        ],
        declarations: [AppComponent,HeaderComponent,SidebarComponent],
        providers: [AuthGuard],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent],
        exports: [
            HeaderComponent,
            SidebarComponent
      ],

    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

I don't why I obtain this excepion:

> Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to
>   common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module,
>   import CommonModule instead. Error: BrowserModule has already been
>   loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor
>   from a lazy loaded module, import

In the future module I import `CommonModule` and not `BrowerModule`. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You have `CommonModule` imported in your `AppModule`. This needs to be `BrowserModule`.

Comment: The problem is you are importing CommonModule and BrowserAnimationsModule. BrowserAnimationsModule internally exports BrowserModule and CommonModule exports are reexported by BrowserModule. Use either of them as per your requirement.

Comment: @SachinJagtap I delete CommonModule and I leave alone . Put in my child.module the commonModule,  but it still not work.

Comment: Can you show your imports of child module.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Import `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `HttpModule` only once (either in your root module or a core module).

import these mentioned modules only once(in app-module only):

`BrowserModule`, `BrowserAnimationsModule`, `LazyLoadImageModule` (if using it), `CarouselModule` (if using it), `InfiniteScrollModule` (if using it), `HttpModule` ( if using it)

Comment: Yes I imported their only once time

Comment: you check it properly?

Comment: Yes I do a research in the source folder with BrowserAnimationsModule and HttpModule like term  and I read that the files where there are the result is app.module. Maybe there are some js library that import browsermodule?

Comment: then install if js library issue npm install browsermodule --save

Comment: I got this error too, and after a lot of pain and suffering BrowserAnimationsModule only worked without complains if imported in app.module.ts. Does anyone know why? I thought angular modules are completely independent.

Answer (score 8):

> Import BrowserAnimationsModule in **AppModule only** because BrowserAnimationsModule by default import BrowserModule, No Need to define BrowserModule in app.module.ts and then import CommonModule in your child / featured module.

```
 @NgModule({
imports:      [ 
                BrowserAnimationsModule
                ]
})    
export class ParentModule {}
```

> Featured / Child Module

```
    @NgModule({
           imports:      [ CommonModule ]
     })   
export class FeaturedModule {}
```

> Hope, this solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

Replace CommonModule with BrowserModule in your AppModule.

```js
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LanguageTranslationModule } from './shared/modules/language-translation/language-translation.module'

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared';

import { SidebarComponent } from './layout/components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './layout/components/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        LanguageTranslationModule,
        AppRoutingModule

    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent,HeaderComponent,SidebarComponent],
    providers: [AuthGuard],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent,
        SidebarComponent
  ],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Did you replace the CommonModule with BrowserModule and import it ?

Comment: yes! I copy your code but it doesn't work! I'm becoming crazy

Comment: Are you importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your other modules other than AppModule ?

Comment: No! I check that only in the app.module the BrowserAnimationsModule  is imported, in the other module is not imported ( the same with BrowserModule)

Comment: Sometimes you may importing a library package which is importing the BrowserModule. check for that aswell.

Comment: @Denuka about your last comment about the library which imports the same module, how are we supposed to fix it, if the duplicate module comes from a library package?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had imported `BrowserModule` in both my root `AppModule` and the `SharedModule` used by feature modules. I removed it from `SharedModule` and that got things working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had to remove the   NoopAnimationsModule,from the imports of child module. In the APPModule i imported it from angular but never used in the imports.
in the app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

My app uses standalone modules and I got this error as well when I added `BrowserAnimationsModule` to my imports list/

I was already importing `CommonModule` which apparently already contains this, so I simply had to remove `BrowserAnimationsModule` and it all worked including my animations