# Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use lazy load one of my modules.

When navigating to the module I'm getting this error:

> BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
>   Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead

**I've removed `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` from my project completely!** but still getting this error. Maybe some other module still use it (`@angular/material`?).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share module code?

Comment: Maybe it is an implicit usage. Do you use `BrowserAnimationsModule` somewhere? Angular Material itself does not include it in its modules.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975675/lazy-loading-browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded/45979219) might help you.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110455/browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded) too

Comment: I am using `BrowserAnimationsModule` on my shared module. I'm importing the shared module to my lazy-loading module as well.

Comment: Try to load the `BrowserAnimationsModule` only once, e.g in your `AppModule`.

Comment: Importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` only on `AppModule` resolves in 
`Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngIf' . . .`

Comment: This is an indication that you need to import the `CommonModule` in the modules where the error occurs. I guess in your `SharedModule`. You can import it in multiple modules, without having to worry about.

Comment: @ChrisY importing `CommonModule` solves this problem but I'm still getting `BrowserModule has already been loaded` when trying to load the lazy module.

Comment: Then I'm stuck too. Maybe you can narrow down the error-causing module by removing module by module from the imports in your AppModule.

Comment: the imports array contains only `HttpClientModule` `SharedModule` and some other self-written modules. Removing `HttpClientModule` caused an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202971/discussion-between-chrisy-and-ranbuch).

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

On my `SharedModule` I had some third party modules that where using `BrowserModule` like:
`RecaptchaModule`, `RecaptchaFormsModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

Since I'm using `SharedModule` on my lazy-module the `BrowserModule` must have re-loaded when I was navigating to the lazy-load route.

I'm importing `RecaptchaModule` and `RecaptchaFormsModule` only on the relevant module.

I'm importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` to my `AppModule`.

I'm importing and exporting `CommonModule` on my `SharedModule`.

I still do not import `BrowserModule` (directly) anywhere.

Thank you for your help @ChrisY.